# Create new list by repeating pattern from another one in R

Tags: r, list

I have a list of color such as ;

**list_color<-c("#8bf6f8","#ac807d")** (**list_color[1]** correspond to the color of the fist list of list  (here Homo_sapiens))

and a list of list such as :

```
list(Homo_sapiens = "Group1", Mus_musclus = c("Group2", 
"Group3", "Group4", "Group5"))

$Homo_sapiens
[1] "G1"

$Mus_musclus
[1] "G2" "G3" "G4" "G5"
```

and I would like to create a `new_list_color` where for each list I rep the color in **list_color** (the rep is the number of Groups within list)

Then this list should look like:

```
new_list_color<-c("#8bf6f8","#ac807d","#ac807d","#ac807d","#ac807d")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the second list is called `data` you can do -

```
new_list_color <- rep(list_color, lengths(data))
new_list_color

#[1] "#8bf6f8" "#ac807d" "#ac807d" "#ac807d" "#ac807d"
```